# NetLogo: create a dynamic number of breeds

Tags: netlogo

how can i create a dynamic number of breeds at runtime?
I want my user to be able to choose the amount of breeds.

I thought about something like

```
to setup_breeds

  let j 1

  while[j <= n_groups][

    breed[j]

  ]

end
```

where `n_groups` is the number of breeds whick is taken from a slider.
But unfortunatly i cannot use `breed` inside a method...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare each breed with the [`breed`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#breed) keyword, so the short answer is: no, you can't have a dynamic number of breeds.

But do you really need actual NetLogo *breeds*? The main purpose of having different breeds is to have different variables for each breed. If that is not case, perhaps you can get away with having a `group-id` turtle variable. To create a certain number of turtles for each of `n_groups`, you could just do something like:

```
turtles-own [ group-id ]

to setup
  clear-all
  let n_groups 10
  let n-turtles-per-group 5
  foreach n-values n_groups [ ? ] [
    create-turtles 10 [ set group-id ? ]
  ]
  ask turtles [ set label group-id ]
  ; do something with only turtles of, e.g., group 2:
  ask turtles with [ group-id = 2 ] [
    fd 5
  ]
end
```

If you think you *really* need breeds, edit your question to tell us why, and we'll see if we can find a solution for you.

**Side note:**

I used `foreach n-values n_groups [ ? ]` to loop through your *n* groups. That's the equivalent of:

```
let i 0
while [ i < n_groups ] [
  set i i + 1
]
```

...but arguably more "NetLogo-*ish*".